# VPN Device behind router/firewall

Tags: vpn, pptp, cisco-vpn

**ROUTER A**: Peplink 310 serving as the gateway/router/firewall at one location.

**ROUTER B**: Linksys RV082 serving as the gateway/router/firewall at another location.

I want to VPN these two locations together.

The Peplink has a PPTP server and has proprietary site-to-site vpn if you had another peplink device.

The Linksys has an IPsec vpn server.

**VPN A**: I also have another spare linksys rv082.

I'm trying to setup the other rv082 (**VPN A**) behind the peplink (**ROUTER A**) and get **VPN A** to talk to **ROUTER B**.

I setup **VPN A** with a lan ip address and plugged one of it's LAN ports into the LAN. I was able to get to it's web interface fine.

On **ROUTER A** I one-to-one nat mapped one of our public ip's to the LAN IP for **VPN A**. I opened TCP 50-51 and UDP 500 to **VPN A**.

I configured the VPN settings on **VPN A** to connect to **ROUTER B**. I did the opposite for **ROUTER B**.

But the vpn doesn't connect.

Then I tried pluging **VPN A**'s wan port into the lan, and gave it another LAN IP. I thought perhaps **VPN A** didn't want to send VPN traffic out over the LAN and wanted do send it over it's WAN.

The vpn still doesn't connect.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar recently, where I set up a VPN originating from a Linksys RV082 from behind a NAT router, so it's definitely possible.

Here are a few suggestions to consider:

- Ensure that [NAT traversal](http://www.peplink.com/index.php?view=faq&id=109&path=22#Site-to-site) (NAT-T) is enabled on the Peplink device
- If the Peplink devices supports IPsec, consider using that instead of the RV082
- Check that one VPN endpoint has keepalive enabled, or try sending traffic down the tunnel to bring up the security association
- You probably need to use the WAN port on VPN A to connect it to the LAN behind Router A. Normally, these devices will only listen establish VPN connections using their `outside` interface.
- If NAT-T is working properly, you don't need to do any port forwarding or NAT mapping on Router A. Try turning off your one-to-one mapping.
- You can get away with only one side of an IPsec security association being configured with a remote peer address. Try setting up VPN a with the remote address for Router B, then configure the security association on Router B to use 0.0.0.0 as the remote peer. It will just listen for a connection that way.

If it still doesn't work, check your logs on both sides, and verify that the Phase 1 and Phase 2 proposals are all using identical parameters.

Comment: Oh wow, this is old. I love how ServerFault picks random old questions to put on the front page. :-)

Comment: Good suggestions still. We actually ended up getting another peplink router at the other site. Been using their proprietary VPN and it works great. It can bond multiple WAN connections and aggregate the bandwidth over the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.  Only small networks use a single router/firewall/vpn device.  Larger networks will have dedicated boxes for routing, firewall, and vpn.

You actually want both ports on the rv082 connected, but you need to set up a second subnet and static routes for the second interface.  like..

```
[internet]
    |
 [router A] (normal lan subnet)
    |
    \-------[rv082] (wan)
               |
    /-------[rv082] (lan)
    |
 [router A] (vpn subnet)
```

not having that wouldn't prevent the vpn from coming up, it would just mean you wouldn't be able to actually route any traffic over the vpn.  to fix the vpn problem you are going to need to enable some logging.  ipsec is a complicated system, but the different phases are easy enough to understand.  Without any logs it is impossible to tell what is wrong.